# Regex to match sql where conditions

Tags: c++, regex, qt

What should be my Regex to match fetch the `WHERE` condition without `(GROUP\\ BY|HAVING|ORDER\\ BY|ASC|DESC|LIMIT)`? It works fine if I have any of the described params. It should also work for both the cases (with or without these parameters)

I need to get `id=1 or id=2`

```
QString query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=1 or id=2"
QString whereString;  

QRegularExpression whereListRegex("\\ WHERE\\ (.*?)\\ (GROUP\\ BY|HAVING|ORDER\\ BY|ASC|DESC|LIMIT)\\ ", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);
QRegularExpressionMatch whereIterator = whereListRegex.match(query);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
QRegularExpression whereListRegex(R"(\sWHERE\s+(.*?)(?:\s+(?:GROUP\s+BY|HAVING|ORDER\s+BY|ASC|DESC|LIMIT)\b|\s*$))", QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9Qj5uE/2)

The regex matches:

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `WHERE` - a string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than linebreak chars as few as possible
- `(?:\s+(?:GROUP\ BY|HAVING|ORDER\ BY|ASC|DESC|LIMIT)\b|\s*$)` - either of the two:

  - `\s+(?:GROUP\s+BY|HAVING|ORDER\s+BY|ASC|DESC|LIMIT)\b` - 1+ whitespaces followed with one of the alternative phrases
  - `|` - or
  - `\s*$` - 0+ whitespaces at the end of string.